# Install Failed or Install Completed

Tags: powershell

I tried to set this up

```
$install = Start-Process -FilePath 'path' -ArgumentList '/qn' -Wait -PassThru
if ($install.ExitCode -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "Install Successful"
} else {
    Write-Host "Install Failed"
}
```

but now it just tells me install successful no matter what even when i break the path it will still tell me install successful. I was wondering what I'm doing wrong and or what else i could do cause this is not working for me, i tried -ne 0 and i get the same result.

Comment: That depends entirely on the installer - if it always exits sucessfully, then the process exit code is not a good indicator :)

Comment: So is there another option for me to get powershell to tell me if the install was successful or not rather than using exitcode?

Comment: Again, depends on the installer - your question doesn't contain any details about it, so hard to say :)

Comment: its a combinations of installers, .msi and .exe, i don't know what more information is needed but i know there has got to be a way to make powershell tell me if the install was successful or failed, rather than having to create a bunch of variables with test path to look and see if the directory is there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to check if the command to start the process was completed, and not the process itself. You can check registry to check that programm instals successfully.

```
$software = "My software name";
$installed = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where { $_.DisplayName -eq $software }) -ne $null

If(-Not $installed) {
    Write-Host "'$software' NOT is installed.";
} else {
    Write-Host "'$software' is installed."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong error code for msiexec.

> 0 -> Installation completed successfully
>
> 1602 -> Operation cancelled by the user.
>
> 1603 -> Fatal error during the installation.
>
> 1604 -> Installation suspended/incomplete.

A complete list of msiexec exit codes are available here: http://docs.netecm.ch/launcher/troubleshooting/msi-exit-codes.html

Fixed code:

```
& msiexec.exe "filepath.msi" /qn
switch ($LastExitCode){
  0 {"Installation completed successfully "}
 1602 {" Operation cancelled by the user."}
 1603 {"Fatal error during the installation."}
 1604 {" Installation suspended/incomplete"}
}
```